# Error contador de vocales juntas en una cadena

Tags: c++, string, funciones

El programa me funciona bien, el programa cuenta cuantas vocales juntas hay en una cadena y cuales son. Pero me muestra al reves, ejemplo: "me muero por ir al rio" me muestra ue io 2 vocales, quiero que me muestre 2 vocales (ue, io). Tan bien queria ver si hay alguna formas mas optima de hacer este programa porque no me parece que sea la forma mas eficiente de hacerlo pero no se me ocurre otra forma.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int contarVocales(char S[],int n)
{int i,c=0;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
     if(S[i]=='a' && S[i+1]=='e')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ae ";}
     if(S[i]=='a' && S[i+1]=='i')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ai ";}
     if(S[i]=='a' && S[i+1]=='o')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ao ";}
     if(S[i]=='a' && S[i+1]=='u')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"au ";}
     if(S[i]=='e' && S[i+1]=='a')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ea ";}
     if(S[i]=='e' && S[i+1]=='i')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ei ";}
     if(S[i]=='e' && S[i+1]=='o')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"eo ";}
     if(S[i]=='e' && S[i+1]=='u')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"eu ";}
     if(S[i]=='i' && S[i+1]=='a')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ia ";}
     if(S[i]=='i' && S[i+1]=='e')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ie ";}
     if(S[i]=='i' && S[i+1]=='o')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"io ";}
     if(S[i]=='i' && S[i+1]=='u')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"iu ";}
     if(S[i]=='o' && S[i+1]=='a')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"oa ";}
     if(S[i]=='o' && S[i+1]=='e')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"oe ";}
     if(S[i]=='o' && S[i+1]=='i')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"oi ";}
     if(S[i]=='o' && S[i+1]=='u')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ou ";}
     if(S[i]=='u' && S[i+1]=='a')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ua ";}
     if(S[i]=='u' && S[i+1]=='e')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ue ";}
     if(S[i]=='u' && S[i+1]=='i')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"ui ";}
     if(S[i]=='u' && S[i+1]=='o')
        {c=c + 1; cout<<"uo ";}
   }
  return c;
}
int main()
{char oracion[30]; int n;
    cout<<"Introduzca la oracion: "; cin.getline(oracion,30);
    n=strlen(oracion);
    cout<<contarVocales(oracion,n)<<" vocales juntas";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No sé si pueda hacer más eficiente pero sí más legible.

Comment: @Mateo si se puede hacer más eficiente

Comment: @Andres agrega una respuesta contando cómo lo harías entonces

Comment: Ya existe esa respuesta. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/570782/86914 Saludos

Answer (score 1):

En vez de tener un `if` para cada caso e ir verificando todas las combinaciones es mejor tener una función que verifique si un caracter es una vocal y con eso el problema se vuelve más fácil de solucionar

Primero creamos la función que nos verificará si el caracter es una vocal, esto lo hacemos con ayuda de un ciclo `for` para recorrer un arreglo de `char` que contiene todas las vocales y si conincide con lo que pasamos por parámetro entonces retornamos `true`, de lo contrario `false`.

```cpp
bool es_vocal(char letra){
    char vocales[] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    for(auto vocal: vocales){
        if(vocal == letra) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Con esa función ya toda la tarea de verificar recae en esta y solo debemos de llamarla en la función de contar vocales.

```cpp
int contar_vocales(int longitud, char palabra[]){
    int ocurrencias = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < longitud - 1; i++){
        // si hay un espacio en blanco omitimos
        // esto si quieres comprobar si las vocales están juntas sin importar el espacio entre ellas.
        if(palabra[i] == ' ') continue; // puedes eliminar esta linea si no quieres lo anterior
        if(es_vocal(palabra[i]) && es_vocal(palabra[i + 1])){
            cout << palabra[i] << palabra[i + 1] << endl;
            ocurrencias++;
        }
    }
    
    return ocurrencias;
}
```

Probamos

```cpp
int main()
{
    char palabra[] = "me muero por ir al rio";
    int cantidad = strlen(palabra);
    int cant_vocales = contar_vocales(cantidad, palabra);
    cout << cant_vocales << " vocales juntas" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Y esto da como resultado

```
ue
io
2 vocales juntas
```

Si quieres que el mensaje de las vocales juntas aparezcan al inicio entonces no debes de poner un `cout` en caso se cumpla la condición, sino que tendras que agregar el mensaje a una variable y devolverla junto con el numero de ocurrencias.

Podrías hacerlo de esta forma:

```cpp
// se transforma en void ya que no regresa nada
// toda la impresión por consola se hace en esta función
void contar_vocales(int longitud, char palabra[]){
    int ocurrencias = 0;
    string msg = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < longitud - 1; i++){
        if(palabra[i] == ' ') continue;
        if(es_vocal(palabra[i]) && es_vocal(palabra[i + 1])){
            msg += string(1, palabra[i]) + string(1, palabra[i + 1]) + "\n";
            ocurrencias++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Hay " << ocurrencias << " vocales juntas:" << endl;
    cout << msg;
}

int main()
{
    char palabra[] = "me muero por ir al rio";
    int cantidad = strlen(palabra);
    contar_vocales(cantidad, palabra);
    return 0;
}
```

Si tienes alguna duda puedes dejarmela en los comentarios :D

Comment: Solo faltaría hacerlo compatible con mayúsculas. Como crítica, puede ser más rápido imprimir las vocales directamente a `cout` o a un [`stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) y luego a `cout`. Habría que hacer un benchmark a ver cuál es mejor.